# Build a custom seconds and minutes input in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Im making an exercise timer and I need an input for seconds and minutes.

The ideal UX would 2 select lists side by side. Tapping on the input would open both lists, so different from the web where you can only focus on one at a time.

Ive made a demo here, although it would need to be in a modal or similar: 
https://snack.expo.io/@jamesweblondon/intelligent-apple

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const minutes = new Array(10).fill('').map((item, index)=>{
  return index;
})
const seconds = new Array(60).fill('').map((item, index)=>{
  return index;
})

const Item = ({text, isSelected, onPress}) => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={onPress}
      style={[styles.item, isSelected && styles.itemIsSelected]}>
      {text}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [selectedMinute, setSelectedMinute] = React.useState(1);
  const [selectedSeconds, setSelectedSeconds] = React.useState(10);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Minutes</Text>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
          {
            minutes.map((item, index)=>{
              return <Item
                onPress={()=>setSelectedMinute(item)} 
                text={item} 
                key={item} 
                isSelected={selectedMinute === index} 
              />
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Seconds</Text>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
          {
            seconds.map((item, index)=>{
              return <Item 
                onPress={()=>setSelectedSeconds(item)} 
                text={item} 
                key={item} 
                isSelected={selectedSeconds === index} 
              />
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 300
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scroll: {
    height: 300
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  item: {
    padding: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  itemIsSelected: {
    backgroundColor: 'gold'
  }
});
```

Is it OK to build your own inputs in React Native? This would be a a bad idea on the web as it would probably result in worse UX (especially for keyboard navigation) and a component that screen readers wouldn't know how to use.

I couldn't find a library that does quite what I need. This is close but you can only have one list open at a time. It also had a major bug with Redux making it unusable for me:
https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select#readme

Ive been trying to use the `Picker` component as I imagine it's more semantic? It works how I need on iOS but not Android (see screenshots):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this will help you. Please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-24h-timepicker

Comment: That's pretty close. iOS is nicer than Android, and for my design full screen with a heading would be best. So essentially I still think I can make a better experience manually, but I'm not sure if this is advisable?

Comment: I would advise you to use a third party. Because manually you need to handle so many cases as well as UI as the android phone has very much in screen dimensions.